# Handling popups in chrome using Java and Selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I want to handle this pop up using selenium and Java.

Any hints how to do it?

Comment: Post HTML code.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Changed title to be shorter and more concise

Answer (score 0):

if it is a popup dialog, you can use `driver.switchTo().alert().accept()`.

if it is a DOM element, you need to find the (x) button and then click on it

Comment: Actually it appears for a very short period of time like 2-3 seconds. I will check with above code and let you know.

Comment: Have you tried to wait for sometime to make sure the dialog appears?
Did you check if it is a custom dialog? (that is is a DOM element)